# Visual basic to open a folder with the window in a specific location?

Tags: vba, ms-access, directory

A task I frequently need to accomplish is opening two folders and moving specific files from one to another. The file names are random enough that I can't effectively automate this.

Currently I need to click the button to open one folder, reposition it on one side of the screen, click the button to open the second folder, reposition it on the other side of the screen, and move the files.

Is there a way, when sending the command to open a window, that I can specify the dimensions or location of the window it opens? Thus I could make one button to open both folders, with one on each side of the screen.

All computers that use this system will have two monitors, so a command of "Maximize this window to monitor 1" and "Maximize this window to monitor 2" would also work.

Current code I use

```
If Len(Dir(CurrentProject.path & "\" & "RecordFiles" & "\" & ID, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir CurrentProject.path & "\" & "RecordFiles" & "\" & ID
End If
Dim path As String
path = CurrentProject.path & "\" & "RecordFiles" & "\" & ID & "\"
Shell "cmd /C start """" /max """ & path & """", vbHide
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplified description of a tool I developed and am using daily as a solution for similar task: On a spreadsheet in A3 path to start folder, in B3 destination folder. Right click in first row lists all file names below A3, which are currently in that path.  Right Click in corresponding cell below B3 moves files A3 to B3 and moves on to next file in next row, giving a preview by opening File Explorer.